# Eclipse Juno null pointer error when publishing

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have just upgraded to 
and now get an error when I try to publish to Apache Tomcat 7.0.30.  The error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.util.PublishHelper.copyFile(PublishHelper.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.util.PublishHelper.copy(PublishHelper.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.util.PublishHelper.publishFull(PublishHelper.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.util.PublishHelper.copy(PublishHelper.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.util.PublishHelper.publishFull(PublishHelper.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.util.PublishHelper.copy(PublishHelper.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.util.PublishHelper.publishFull(PublishHelper.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.PublishOperation2.publishDir(PublishOperation2.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.PublishOperation2.execute(PublishOperation2.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.performTasks(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:1290)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:933)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3108)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Note that I did a clean install of Juno, created a new workspace for it (ie. did not copy/convert/rename the old eclipse workspace) and created the server from scratch in Juno!

TIA